# Leave a column what I wanted after 'groupby' and calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a table of test results,
and want to know the person who is the best and who is the worst for each subject.

The example of the input table:

| Subject | Score | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Math | 27 | Student1 |
| History | 43 | Student2 |
| Math | 44 | Student3 |
| History | 50 | Student1 |
| Science | 7 | Student1 |
| History | 10 | Student3 |
| Science | 43 | Student2 |

I want to make output table like following table:

| Subject | BestScr | BestStud | WorstScr | WorstStud |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math | 44 | Student3 | 27 | Student1 |
| History | 50 | Student1 | 10 | Student3 |
| Science | 43 | Student2 | 7 | Student1 |

Following code is what I tried:

```
inputTableGrouped = inputTable.groupby(['Subject'])

outputTableGrouped['BestScr'] = inputTableGrouped.Score.max()
outputTableGrouped['WorstScr'] = inputTableGrouped.Score.min()

outputTable = outputTableGrouped.reset_index()
```

But this way, I cannot find the way to record student name.
What should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indices by maximal and minimal `Score` and select mtched rows with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), convert `Subject` to indices with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and join together:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Subject', sort=False)['Score'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax'])

df11 = df.loc[df1['idxmax']].set_index('Subject').add_prefix('Best')
df22 = df.loc[df1['idxmin']].set_index('Subject').add_prefix('Worst')

df = df11.join(df22).reset_index()
print (df)
   Subject  BestScore  BestName  WorstScore WorstName
0     Math         44  Student3          27  Student1
1  History         50  Student1          10  Student3
2  Science         43  Student2           7  Student1
```

Or convert `Name` to index, so you can use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and `min` with `max` functions:

```
df = (df.set_index('Name')
        .groupby('Subject', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg(BestScr=('Score', 'max'),
            BestStud= ('Score', 'idxmax'),
            WorstScr=('Score', 'min'),
            WorstStud=('Score', 'idxmax'))
)
print (df)
   Subject  BestScr  BestStud  WorstScr WorstStud
0     Math       44  Student3        27  Student3
1  History       50  Student1        10  Student1
2  Science       43  Student2         7  Student2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With idxmax and idxmin, I can make the table what I want!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
(df.groupby('Subject', as_index=False, sort=False)
    .agg(**{'BestScr': ('Score', 'max'),
            'BestStd': ('Score', lambda s: df.loc[s.idxmax(), 'Name']),
            'WorstScr': ('Score', 'min'),
            'WorstStd': ('Score', lambda s: df.loc[s.idxmin(), 'Name']),
                            })
)
```

Output:

```
   Subject  BestScr   BestStd  WorstScr  WorstStd
0     Math       44  Student3        27  Student1
1  History       50  Student1        10  Student3
2  Science       43  Student2         7  Student1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
out = df.set_index(['Subject', 'Name'])['Score'].unstack()
out['BestScr'], out['BestStud'], out['WorstScr'], out['WorstStud'] = out.max(
    1), out.idxmax(1), out.min(1), out.idxmin(1)
out = out.drop(columns=out.columns[out.columns.str.startswith('Student')])
out = out.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Subject  BestScr  BestStud  WorstScr WorstStud
0  History     50.0  Student1      10.0  Student3
1     Math     44.0  Student3      27.0  Student1
2  Science     43.0  Student2       7.0  Student1
```